# What was the cheap homemade Star Wars ripoff on Amazon Prime called?

Tags: story-identification

I remember there being a really awful Star Wars ripoff, created with action figures and not even stop motion, the producers just grabbed the action figures by the feet and waved them around.

This somehow made it to Amazon Prime video about 6 months or so ago. Now it is gone, and with it any trace of its  existence.

Has anyone seen it, and still remembers the name?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the [Robot Chicken: Star Wars](https://www.google.ca/search?q=robot+chicken+star+wars&rlz=1C1OCLT_enCA757CA757&oq=robot+chicken+star+wars&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3464j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) parody series?  It's a lot older than 6 months, though...

Comment: Could it be [Star Wars: Uncut](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Uncut)? Some portions of the film utilized action figures.

Comment: I've not seen this, but the description of the presentation perfectly describes "Chuckamation", which was used for "Action League NOW!", a segment of the Nickelodeon show Kb-BLAM! with a short-lived solo series. Worth a look if you've never seen it.

Comment: It was actually titled star wars. It just had a plot like it. young Farmer Boys family gets killed by an evil empire,   old master - happens to be a Samuel Jackson figure in a Cowboy hat - save him and tells him his father was an space astro something knight and so on.

Comment: And it is was produced way worse than action league now - like two guys in their room filmed it with their fathers camcorder. Thats why i wondered how it got onto amazon prime video

Comment: FTR I think [Hardware Wars](https://youtu.be/WYOSZwe8Ibk) was on prime a while back, but it's live action

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like it could be the Adam and Joe show. This was a low budget comedy show from the late 90s made by Adam Buxton and Joe Cornish which included a variety of offbeat sketches, some of which were made using Star Wars toys.  I think it matches your description as they did clearly move the figures by hand and it had a"home made" feel. However, stop motion was used also, as well as superimposing real human moving mouths onto the figures' faces for when the characters talk. I have noticed that the show is available to buy via Amazon Prime, so it seems possible it could have been on the "Included with Prime" service, which may be how you saw it.

Comment: i am afraid not, it was no scetch show - it was a continuous series with an overarching plot and there really way no finesse to it - except the cheapest explosion effects from any video editing software - no stop motion, no human mouths